# Restart Docker Network after Resuming VM

Tags: networking, docker

Whenever I suspend/resume my VMs the docker networking fails to function (e.g. timeouts between containers and the host, etc.). I'm using docker in the VM, the VM is not controlled by docker.

This issue can be resolved by restarting docker (`sudo systemctl restart docker`) but I would prefer to just restart/reset the network component so I can add it to a resume script.

Does docker offer an api to restart its network component?

Comment: Is the adapter `up` on the container? What does `ip addr show` produce?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
docker network connect multi-host-network [container_name]
```

Allegedly this will connect a running container to a network. Though it seems that it should reconnect automatically.

Comment: Just tried it. The container is connected but no traffic goes trough. Disconnect/connect did not help either.